# How to connect consecutive words of a text in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph

I have to connect consecutive words of a text in a dictionary.

The text is:

```
text = "Hello world I am Josh"
```

The dictionary would be:

```
dict = {Hello:[world], world:[Hello, I], I:[am, world], am:[I, Josh], Josh:[am]}
```

The keys are all the words in the text, the values are the consecutive words. 
Anyone has an idea to abstain this?

1. I would split the text. To obtain all the words in a list.
2. I would use the words as the keys of the dictionary.
3. ?

Comment: What would you expect if the text was something like "Simon and Simon read the already read book"?

Comment: Good question, perhaps the values of the dicts would be better as collections.Counter than lists

Answer (score 4):

Using the  [`pairwise` recipe from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

adjacent = collections.defaultdict(list)
for left, right in pairwise(text.split()):
    adjacent[right].append(left)
    adjacent[left].append(right)
```

Your question doesn't consider the possibility that a word appears in the sentence more than once. You might want a `set` rather than a `list` of adjacent words. Punctuation in the sentence could also ruin your day, so depending on your requirements you might need to do more than just `split()`.

Comment: Damn, I just wrote out literally the exact same code (with different variable names) and was about to post it.